# Do L-systems have a corresponding automata?

Tags: automata

So, I was reading about L-systems and it seems that L-systems are in many ways analogous to context-free grammars. Is there a corresponding automata for this? I can't seem to find anything on the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lindenmayer's original papers define them using arrays of finite state machines. The outputs at each time are the states at the next time, which also serve as inputs to the neighbors, much like a cellular automaton. Unlike cellular automata, the machines can output strings, and each additional symbol becomes the state of a new machine in the array.